# Apex - remove special characters from a string except for ''+"

Tags: string, salesforce, apex

In Apex, I want to remove all the special characters in a string except for "+". This string is actually a phone number. I have done the following.

```
      String sampleText = '+44 597/58-31-30';
      sampleText = sampleText.replaceAll('\\D','');
      System.debug(sampleText);
```

So, what it prints is 44597583130.
But I want to keep the sign + as it is represents 00.

Can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solutions

```apex
String sampleText = '+44 597/58-31-30';
// exclude all characters which you want to keep 
System.debug(sampleText.replaceAll('[^\\+|\\d]',''));

// list explicitly each char which must be replaced    
System.debug(sampleText.replaceAll('/|-| ',''));
```

Output in both case will be the same

> |DEBUG| +44597583130
>
> |DEBUG| +44597583130

**Edit**

```apex
String sampleText = '+0032 +497/+59-31-40';
System.debug(sampleText.replaceAll('(?!^\\+)[^\\d]',''));
```

> |DEBUG|+0032497593140

Comment: Hi @Pavel, Thank You for you answer. Could we change the first one in a way that it makes sure + is only available at the start of the string ?  So that +0032 +497/+59-31-40 becomes  +0032497593140 ?